# Can we replace a binding handler with component

Tags: knockout.js

I have implemented some binding handlers, but I just came across the component concept. I think it is more clear.

Could we make components instead of binding handlers, e.g. a simple grid component instead of a simple grid binding handler?

Component is different than template as it has it's own data model, but binding handlers and components seem to be same but only different in implementation.  Please help me understand the difference between them. Could the simple grid binding handler given as an example be implemented as a component instead of a binding handler ?

**Simplifying the question in one line:**

> Should and Could [this](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/grid.html) be a Component instead of being a custom binding ?

Comment: Down voters plz add a comment! To educate why this isn't a valid good question.

Comment: Here's a few things I noticed about the question that may be somewhat problematic (not sure if you can fix all of 'em). It's really a rather broad question, and at the moment (now that it's also terse) it's asking for opinions. There is no code included, no *specific* scenario or problem. You also haven't shared any research: why would you think they are interchangeable, i.e. what part of the docs, source code, or examples do you have that would indicate they would be?

Comment: A testimony to that would be the fact that I still think, as far as the question *is* answerable, that my current answer should do the trick. Your last edit was very minor, and didn't add many specifics at all - in fact it introduced more unclarity (what "simple grid binding handler" do you speak of? how would it be included as a component? etc)

Answer (score -1):

Components approach is more modular with functionality as dynamic loading of templates. For larger projects this is an ideal solution, since you can break up the project in more modular architecture (reuse, code isolation ..).
Communication between components can be addressed using pubsub messaging for example.

The conventional route, ie binding syntax, remain in many of my usecases still the preferred way. Reason: you have more flexiblity in the 'hosting html page' with regards to working with attributes on the elements you're targeting with the binding.

It is not uncommon to mix the different approaches. BTW, there are more syntaxes available, like the {{varName}} .. have a look at the Knockout Punches plugin written by mbest.

Hope this helps!